# How to dynamically find the path of an exe compiled with PyInstaller?

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, pyinstaller

I need to add as startup an exe compiled with PyInstaller when I run it.
The problem is that I don't know how to dynamically find the path of the exe compiled with PyInstaller.

I used this function on my script:

```
def AddToRegistry():

    # in python __file__ is the instant of
    # file path where it was executed
    # so if it was executed from desktop,
    # then __file__ will be
    # c:\users\current_user\desktop
    pth = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    # name of the python file with extension
    s_name="\\"+os.path.basename(__file__)


    # joins the file name to end of path address
    address=pth+s_name

    # key we want to change is HKEY_CURRENT_USER
    # key value is Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
    key = reg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER
    key_value = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

    # open the key to make changes to
    open = reg.OpenKey(key,key_value,0,reg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)

    # modifiy the opened key
    reg.SetValueEx(open,"any_name",0,reg.REG_SZ,address)

    # now close the opened key
    reg.CloseKey(open)
```

In this way, the program finds the .py file path and doesn't find the exe path.
I need to add as startup the exe and not the .py.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use an installer (msi, or something like InnoSetup) which is way easier and more robust.

Comment: Here's how to get [runtime information](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/runtime-information.html) that's in the PyIntaller documentation.